# Append "Add New" button in Grid Listing, on a Form

Tags: adminhtml, grid, model, ui-form, magento2.4.4

A custom module has `Foo` and `Bar` Models. In the `Foo` element's Form, there exists a grid listing of `Bar` items which belong to that `Foo`. This is an excerpt from the `view/adminhtml/ui_component/bf_foo_form.xml` file:

```
<insertListing name="bf_foo_form_bar_grid">
    <settings>
        <externalProvider>bf_foo_form_bar_grid.bf_foo_grid_data_source</externalProvider>
        <loading>false</loading>
        <autoRender>true</autoRender>
        <dataScope>bf_foo_form_bar_grid</dataScope>
        <ns>bf_foo_form_bar_grid</ns>
        <imports>
            <link name="foo_id">${ $.provider }:data.foo_id</link>
        </imports>
        <exports>
            <link name="foo_id">${ $.externalProvider }:params.foo_id</link>
        </exports>
    </settings>
</insertListing>
```

This is an excerpt from the `view/adminhtml/ui_component/bf_foo_form_bar_grid.xml` file where I try to add the `Add new Bar` button:

```
<settings>
    <spinner>listing_columns</spinner>
    <deps>
        <dep>bf_foo_form_bar_grid.bf_foo_grid_data_source</dep>
    </deps>
    <buttons>
        <button name="add">
            <url path="*/bar/new"/>
            <class>primary</class>
            <label translate="true">Add new Bar</label>
        </button>
    </buttons>
</settings>
```

As that code did not add the `Add new Bar` button, I tried another approach in the same `view/adminhtml/ui_component/bf_foo_form_bar_grid.xml` file:

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="new_bar" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">new_bar</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Add new Bar</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/bar/new</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

However, that did not work either! This is a screenshot of a `Foo` item, with a `Bar` item below, and the place where I'd like to add the `Add new Bar` button:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add button in `fieldset` before `insertListing`

`app/code/Acme/Bar/view/adminhtml/ui_component/foo_form.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <!-- ... -->
    <fieldset name="...">
        <container name="button_set">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/components/complex</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="null"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <container name="add_button" class="Acme\Bar\Ui\Component\Form\Url\AddNewFoo" component="Acme_Bar/js/form/element/link-button">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="null"/>
                        <item name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Add New Bar</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </container>
        </container>
        <insertListing name="bf_foo_form_bar_grid">
            <!-- ... -->
        </insertListing>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

`app/code/Acme/Bar/view/base/web/js/form/element/link-button.js`

```js
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
    'mage/translate',
], function ($, Button, alert, $t) {
    'use strict';

    return Button.extend({
        action: function() {
            if (this.href) {
                $('body').trigger('processStart');
                window.location.href = this.href;
            } else {
                alert({content: $t('No URL assigned')});
            }
        }
    });
});
```

`app/code/Acme/Bar/Ui/Component/Form/Url/AddNewFoo`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\Bar\Ui\Component\Form\Url;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;

class AddNewFoo extends Field
{
    protected UrlInterface $urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

    public function prepare(): void
    {
        parent::prepare();

        $routePath   = '*/bar/new';
        $routeParams = [
            // optional current foo id
        ];

        $config = $this->getData('config');
        $config = array_merge($config, [
            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($routePath, $routeParams),
        ]);

        $this->setData('config', $config);
    }
}
```

Comment: **Perfect, thank you Victor!** Answer accepted. Would you know how to redirect to the relevant Foo when saving?

Comment: 1. See comment `optional current foo id`, you can pass current foo into bar form, after into save action and after save redirect to foo edit page back by id

Comment: Yes, I did add the current `foo_id` there, and I use it to populate each Bar's `foo_id` field (read from the URL in Javascript). Thanks, I'll use `save_after` to redirect.